# Azure AD - Set Password Policy via GraphAPI

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to implement an Account Lockout policy in Azure AD as described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj943764.aspx, in particular the "Account Lockout" feature.

It seems the default is to lockout the account after 10 attempts, but I never see a CAPTCHA.

How do I set/unset the password policy using the Graph API? If it can't be done that way, is there another way?